# AngularJS - Some dynamic contents loads very late

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have an Angular JS application in which some dynamic rows of data are loaded through a rest API. This section of html data are loaded very late after the whole page is loaded and hence looks bad.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="rows1 in entity.pageSection1Rows">
        <!-- Around five html columns  -->
        <!-- The CONTENTS here loads very late after the whole page is loaded -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="rows2 in entity.pageSection2Rows">
        <!-- Around five html columns  -->
        <!-- The CONTENTS here loads very late after the whole page is loaded -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    myApp.controller('createController', function($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.entity = {};

    $http.get("/restapi/serviceA")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.entity.pageSection1Rows = data;
    });

    $http.get("/restapi/serviceB")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.entity.pageSection2Rows = data;
    });

    // Rest APIs to load data for drop downs    
    $http.get("/restapi/dropdown1")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.dropdown1 = data;
    });

    $http.get("/restapi/dropdown2")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.dropdown2 = data;
    });

    $http.get("/restapi/dropdown3")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.dropdown3 = data;
    });

    $http.get("/restapi/dropdown4")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.dropdown4 = data;
    });



    $scope.add = function() {
        $http.post("/restapi/entity", $scope.entity).success(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
            $location.path('/home');    
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
            console.log("Error : " +statusText);
        });
    }

})
```

Comment: You can either add those calls to routeProvider to make sure they are loaded before loading the page, or add a ng-show that is false if all data is not yet loaded, and show a loading... spinner or whatever

Comment: So, i can give you an advice. Youse resolve section in routes config. for example: `route.when('/', { resolve : { dropdown1: function ($http) { ... }} })`

Comment: here is example http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx